# How can I filter a dataframe's column of datetime just with the date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

I have a dataframe as follow:

| dateTime | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-23 20:00:00 | 553761065 |
| 2021-03-19 20:00:00 | 553845822 |
| 2021-02-05 12:05:00 | 553549067 |
| 2021-02-02 22:05:00 | 553599668 |
| 2021-03-23 05:15:00 | 557070939 |
| 2021-03-23 05:15:00 | 557070939 |

Now, I want to filter id numbers based on the datetime column and compare them by today's date. But I want to check just date as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

df = read_csv('test.csv')

df[(df['dateTime'] == pd.datetime.now().date())]
```

However, it does not work and always the dataframe is empty. Please take care to change the dates if you want to test the dataset!

Thanks

Comment: `df[df.dateTime.dt.normalize() == pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()]`

Comment: `df[df.dateTime.dt.date == pd.Timestamp('now').date()]`

Comment: `df.set_index('dateTime').loc[pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas get date from datetime stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004229/pandas-get-date-from-datetime-stamp)

Comment: Unfortunately no!
But, this is working:

df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today = date.today()
a = df.loc[df['dateTime'] == today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
print(a)